# Django annotation is not working with order_by

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get last 100 records of MyModel order_by('-end_date') and do a SUM annotate on different winner types them

```
MyModel.objects.all()[:100].order_by('-end_game_time').values('winner').annotate(total=Count('winner'))
```

result query is as below and I don't have expected groups

```
<QuerySet [{'winner': 3, 'total': 1}, {'winner': 15, 'total': 1}, 'total': 1}, {'winner': 3, 'total': 1}, {'winner': 5, 'total': 1}, {'winner': 15, 'total': 1}, {'winner': 5, 'total': 1}, {'winner': 3, 'total': 1}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

generated query is like

```
SELECT "game_mymodel"."winner", COUNT("game_mymodel"."winner") AS "total" FROM "game_mymodel" GROUP BY "game_mymodel"."winner", "game_mymodel"."end_game_time" ORDER BY "game_mymodel"."end_game_time" DESC LIMIT 100
```

but when I don't have the order_by the result is as I expected

```
MyModel.objects.all()[:100].values('winner').annotate(total=Count('winner'))
Out[52]: <QuerySet [{'winner': 5, 'total': 43}, {'winner': 1, 'total': 2}, {'winner': 15, 'total': 51}, {'winner': 2, 'total': 42}, {'winner': 3, 'total': 43}]>
```

and generated query group_by part is different

```
SELECT "game_mymodel"."winner", COUNT("game_mymodel"."winner") AS "total" FROM "game_mymodel" GROUP BY "game_mymodel"."winner" LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to achieve what you want to do in single query, what you want in SQL is:

```
SELECT "game_mymodel"."winner", COUNT("game_mymodel"."winner") AS "total" FROM "game_mymodel" GROUP BY "game_mymodel"."winner" ORDER BY "game_mymodel"."end_game_time" DESC LIMIT 100
```

which is not a valid sql query, so you need to have a sub-query to select 100 elements and then apply your aggregation on them.

First build the sub-query:

```
top_100_games = MyModel.objects.order_by('-end_game_time')[:100].only('id').all()
```

And then use it in main query:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=top_100_games).values('winner').annotate(total=Count('winner'))
```